# Why is it always "module 'xxx' has no attribute 'xxx'"?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, tabula, python-camelot

i am using pycharm professional, what is bugging me today is, lots of modules i call seems won't work, forexample, plotly, tabula-py, and camelot.

From the attached pic below, you can see, i am even working in virtual environment, and just did pip install camelot.

For example, now i tried to import camelot, and read_pdf. An error comes up, and says "NO module named "camelot".

I tried pip remove, and pip install again; i have also tried pip3 install, similar errors showed up, saying no such module, or attribute.

What is wrong with my pycharm? and how to fix it?
[image: m]
By the way, in the case of plotly. I tried open it with Terminal > jupyter notebook, then run the code, it worked.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html#install-deps) to install dependencies and then these instructions (https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html#install) to install camelot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check your Python interpreter. See if your python interpreter in virtual env is the same as the pip install location.
2. Try quit the program, and the turn it back on a few times see if it will improve.
3. remember to wait for the indexing. it may take a while.